# Trying to Set Up a Mobile Version of a Site With Its Own Theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm trying to create a mobile version of a site for a client. So http://example.com would be the main site and http://m.example.com would be the mobile site. I have it set up as a subdirectory, and they both point to the same database. In the mobile directory's wp-config file, I have

```
define('WP_SITEURL');
define('WP_HOME');
define('TEMPLATEPATH');
define('STYLESHEETPATH');
```

defined and pointing to the mobile site and correct theme in the mobile directory. I go to the mobile site to change the theme to the mobile theme I have set up. However, when I go check the main site, it also has the mobile theme set. When I change it back to the main theme, the same thing happens on the mobile site. Did I overlook something?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any main functional difference between the two themes? Or is it just supposed to look different?

Comment: For now, just look different.